# Victory Charts background grid

Tags: reactjs, charts, visualization, victory-charts

Is it possible to display a grid like this using Victory charts?

[image]

So far I can only get a grid with both vertical and horizontal lines on top of my bars likes this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The horizontal bars can be removed by removing stroke style.
The vertical bars which I wanted to keep can be 'moved' behind by changing the order of the elements as noted here: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/layout/#svg-render-order

Answer (score 5):

By providing

```
style={{
      grid: { stroke: '#ddd444', strokeWidth: 1.5 },
    }}
```

to your dependant axis like

```
<VictoryAxis
        dependentAxis
        tickFormat={(tick) => `${tick}`}
        style={{
          grid: { stroke: '#F4F5F7', strokeWidth: 0.5 },
        }}
      />
```

you will achieve desired result.